# Remote image resizing fails

Tags: php, image, resize

I have an image upload form in my webpage and scripts(pointing to "handleImage.php") so that I can store on my server a full copy of the image and its thumb.

I noticed that it works perfectly for images not exceeding 500K but for bigger images I can't create the thumbnail version and the scripts stuck on a blank page (handleImage.php).

My server is Aruba.

Those following are my scripts:

**handleImage.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{

 foreach($_FILES['pictures']['name'] as $number=>$file)
 {
  if($_FILES['pictures']['error'][$number]==UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
  {
    //i need to store full image and small in folder
    $ext=pathinfo($_FILES['pictures']['name'][$number],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $folder="upload".time();

    mkdir('/web/htdocs/www.mysite.it/home/img/events/eventsdone/'.$folder);

$destinationFile="/web/htdocs/www.mysite.it/home/img/events/eventsdone/".$folder."/full.".$ext;    
    $pathPic="/web/htdocs/www.mysite.it/home/img/events/eventsdone/".$folder."/";
    $ret=@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pictures']['tmp_name'][$number],$destinationFile);  


if($ret==FALSE)
{
  throw new UploadErrorException(); 
}

$pathThumb=$pathPic."thumb.".$ext;
$resizemgr = new ResizeManager($destinationFile);
$resizemgr -> resizeImage(200,130, 'crop');
$resizemgr -> saveImage($pathThumb, 100); 

    [...]

header("Location:event.php?id={$_POST['id']}");
    }


        }   
}
```

}

**resizeManager.php**

```
Class ResizeManager
    {
        // *** Class variables
        private $image;
        private $width;
        private $height;
        private $imageResized;

        function __construct($fileName)
        {
            // *** Open up the file
            $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

            // *** Get width and height
            $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
            $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function openImage($file)
        {
            // *** Get extension
            $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

            switch($extension)
            {
                case '.jpg':
                case '.jpeg':
                    $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                    break;
                case '.gif':
                    $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                    break;
                case '.png':
                    $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                    break;
                default:
                    $img = false;
                    break;
            }
            return $img;
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
        {
            // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
            $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

            $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


            // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


            // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
            if ($option == 'crop') {
                $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
        {

           switch ($option)
            {
                case 'exact':
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    break;
                case 'portrait':
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    break;
                case 'landscape':
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    break;
                case 'auto':
                    $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                    break;
                case 'crop':
                    $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                    break;
            }
            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
        {
            $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
            $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
            return $newWidth;
        }

        private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
        {
            $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
            $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
            return $newHeight;
        }

        private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
        {
            if ($this->height < $this->width)
            // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
            {
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
            }
            elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
            // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
            {
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            }
            else
            // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
            {
                if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                } else {
                    // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
            }

            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
        {

            $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
            $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

            if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
            } else {
                $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
            }

            $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
            $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
        {
            // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
            $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
            $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

            $crop = $this->imageResized;
            //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

            // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
        {
            // *** Get extension
            $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
            $extension = strtolower($extension);

            switch($extension)
            {
                case '.jpg':
                case '.jpeg':
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                        imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                    }
                    break;

                case '.gif':
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                        imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                    }
                    break;

                case '.png':
                    // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                    $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                    // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                    $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                         imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                    }
                    break;

                // ... etc

                default:
                    // *** No extension - No save.
                    break;
            }

            imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
        }


        ## --------------------------------------------------------

    }
```

Where's the problem??Which parameter(maybe php.ini settingd) this issue could be depending on?

ps is working perfectly on Local environment

Thanks
 luca

Comment: Maybe the script times out?.. Try adding "set_time_limit(60);" to handleimage.php

Comment: Check your post_max_size and upload_max_filesize settings in your php.ini. Both these values should be bigger than the size of the file you're trying to upload.

Comment: @Kristoffer la Cour not working..same issue..a blank handleImage.php page
@Andras Szepeshazi upload_max_filesize= 25M and post_max_size=30M..file that Im testing is just 900K!

Comment: @Kristoffer la Cour even if I added "set_time_limit(60)" the blank page appears after 20 seconds..maybe default setting is not overwritable?either ways in server php.ini max_execution_time=120..=S

Comment: Well then that's not the problem, my next guess would be the memory as @Sabeen Malik suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you look into log files. Seems like this could be related to memory_limit setting in php.ini, looking in the log files you might find fatal error messages to this effect (Fatal error: Out of memory).

Comment: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39114612 bytes) It's soo big but im testing with a 900K jpg..why?

Comment: 39114612 bytes = ~300kb. Did you try increasing your memory limit to, say, on the safe side, 16mb?

Comment: @luca Your allowed size is 64mb, i would recommend increasing this to 128mb, i believe thats the default these days.

Comment: @luca the memory refers to the total memory that is being used to manipulate the image, the bigger the image the more memory and CPU will be needed to run graphic operations on it.